# iPhone + macbook + mirror : How can I see/mirror my iPhone's screen on my macbook?

Tags: mobile-automation, iphone

I'm automating ios app. For demo purpose I wanted to mirror my iPhone's screen on my macbook. How can I do it?

I am using OS X with version 10.11.4 and iPhone iOS version 8.3

Question - How can I see/mirror my iPhone's screen on my macbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have OS X Yosemite and iOS 8 or anything higher than that, try,

1. Connect your iPhone, iPad or iPod touch to your Mac via a Lightning
   Cable.
2. Open QuickTime on your Mac, and select File > New Movie Recording.
3. A recording window will appear. Click the arrow next to the Record
   button, and select your iPhone from the dropdown menu that appears.
4. Click the Record button and go about your business on your iPhone.
5. Once you're done, click the Stop button and save the video.

If all you want to do is play, I found you can skip steps 4 and 5.

Just keep in mind, it doesn't work if you are in a phone call.